# Change File name , Got weird result

Tags: python, file

I have massive folder full of random images name 
 so i want to Rename all file according to number from 1 to ... inf
**however** , its got to weird result in the middle of success
[image: Weird Error here]

```
import os
from time import perf_counter , sleep
start = perf_counter()
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(BASE_DIR)
folder = input("Folder of Images:")
data = BASE_DIR+f"/{folder}"
images = os.listdir(data)
counter = 0
for i in images:
    counter += 1
    checker = i.split(".")
    try:
        done = os.rename(data+f"/{i}",data+f"/{counter}.{checker[1]}")   
        print(f"Images {i} converted")
        sleep(0.1)
    except:
        print(f"{i} is not converted")
print(f"Finish at {perf_counter()}")
```

You may see i put `sleep(0.1)` because i thought `Maybe the process so fast that the number were messed up` , but still does not get the expected result 
 More weird , there is IE file at `file 175`

Comment: did u checked the original names of the files which was weird renamed? probably the original name is behind the bug. here's my work-around: put the files that didnt followed the renaming process (files with original names) in a folder and apply the script, did they still weird renamed? if yes then maybe a dash or a hyphen is bugging the renaming process.

Comment: @CYREX Oh man , you saved my day..so i wrote a script that check every type of images and seem there are several format other than png and jpeg

Comment: @CYREX so i'll modified my script , to check for the file type and only change for png and jpg (since both format are popular)..is that seem okay?

Comment: happy for u bro, i got such bug few months ago and somone gave me this precious hint, today i gave it to u, 2morrow you'll give it to someone else and so on. stay safe  PS: keep testing what you think is correct till you reach what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately , the problem is cause by File type 
Change the script to check the file type first
and than change images that have png or jpg (since both are very popular )
[image: File Type]